# Derivation of the Iterative Reweighted Least Squares Solution for $ {L}_{1} $ Regularized Least Squares Problem

Tags: regression, least-squares, convex, irls

I'm trying to fitting a line with IRLS with L1 norm, but I'm struggling to understand why my idea is wrong.

1 - init the weights $w$

2 - fit with simple LS and obtain a starting model $\beta_0$

3 - at each iteration t then until convergence do:

- compute the residuals $e = |y - x\beta_0|$
- update the weights $w = \dfrac{1}{e}$ ? (Not sure about this)
- build the matrix $W = diag(w)$ ? (Not sure about this)
- update the model $(x'Wx)x'Wy$

Can someone give an explanation of what am I doing wrong, cause I'm not sure if I update the weights in the right way.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous - the title of your question suggests you would like to fit a least squares problem with an L1 regularization term using IRLS (which you can do as in the answer below) but your code suggests instead that you would like to fit a regression line using L1 loss, following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares. Which of those two would you like to do? And why do you think that your L1 regression is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IRLS for the LASSO / Least Squares with $ {L}_{1} $ Regularization problem is as following:

$$ \arg \min_{x} \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} + \lambda \left\| x \right\|_{1} = \arg \min_{x} \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} + \lambda {x}^{T} W {x} $$

Where $ W $ is a diagonal matrix - $ {W}_{i, i} = \frac{1}{ \left| {x}_{i} \right| } $.
This comes from $ \left\| x \right\|_{1} = \sum_{i} \left| {x}_{i} \right| = \sum_{i} \frac{ {x}_{i}^{2} } { \left| {x}_{i} \right| } $.

Now, the above is just [Tikhonov Regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization).
Yet, since $ W $ depends on $ x $ one must solve it iteratively (Also this cancels the 2 factor in Tikhonov Regularization, As the derivative of $ {x}^{T} W x $ with regard to $ x $ while holding $ x $ as constant is $ \operatorname{diag} \left( \operatorname{sign} \left( x \right) \right) $ which equals to $ W x $):

$$ {x}^{k + 1} = \left( {A}^{T} A + \lambda {W}^{k} \right)^{-1} {A}^{T} b $$

Where $ {W}_{i, i}^{K} = \frac{1}{ \left| {x}^{k}_{i} \right| } $.

Initialization can be by $ W = I $.

Pay attention that you better use ADMM or Coordinate Descent.

Comment: The OP uses L1 (absolute) loss, as used in robust regression, not the L2 loss mentioned in your answer.

Comment: @sebp, You `-1` without a reason. The method of IRLS (Iterative Reweighted Least squares) is about solving the $ {L}_{1} $ problem by adaptive weight to imitate it. I solved for $ {L}_{1} $ and this is the IRLS solution. Pay attention to how $ {W}^{k} $ is defined to imitate $ {L}_{1} $ Norm.

Comment: I can somehow see what you are trying to say in your answer, but I find it confusing. Your initial objective is squared error with a LASSO penalty instead of least absolute deviation. After transformation to a weighted least squares problem the weights $W_{i,i}$ in your answer only contain the unknown $x_i$, whereas it should be the residuals.

Comment: @sebp, I didn't invent anything here. Your `-1` has no justification. This is the correct derivation of the IRLS for the problem I stated above.

Comment: Could those who -1 please comment why? This is a correct derivation of the IRLS to the problem stated above.

Comment: This is a correct answer - @sebp the question is not about doing regression with L1 loss, but about doing least squares regression with L1 regularization, and how to solve it via IRLS. You can find details of the method in Jianqing Fan and Runze Li. (2001) Variable selection via nonconcave
penalized likelihood and its oracle properties. A similar recipe is used to approximate L0 regularized regression via IRLS, see https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0148620